# What is the equivalent of the applet getGraphics() in Android. And how can I "draw" outside the onDraw()

Tags: java, android

I need to get the graphics context in Android and I have read that it is not possible to draw outside the `onDraw()`, how can I handle the problem because I need the graphic context to draw outside the `onDraw()`

I have posted the part of code I have problems with.

The is Prof. David Eck’s code in the applet where I am getting the problem.

```
synchronized void putSquare(int row, int col, int colorNum) {

         // draw one cell of the maze, to the graphics context "graphics"
        int w = totalWidth / columns;  // width of each cell
        int h = totalHeight / rows;    // height of each cell
        Graphics graphics = getGraphics();// This is the problem

            graphics.setColor(colorArray[colorNum]);
            graphics.fillRect( (col * w) + left, (row * h) + top, w, h );
}
```

I have tried to convert it to Android

```
synchronized void putSquare(int row, int col, int colorNum, Canvas canvas) {
             try {
                 canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);// nullpointerexception

                   synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                   Paint paint = new Paint():

                    // draw one cell of the maze, to the graphics context "graphics"
                   int w = totalWidth / columns;  // width of each cell
                   int h = totalHeight / rows;    // height of each cell
                   apaint.drawColor(color[colorNum]);
                    canvas.drawRect( (col * w) + left, (row * h) + top, w, h,  paint);
               }
             }


             finally {
                if (aCanvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(aCanvas);
                }
            }
}
```

putSquare() is called by makeMaze()

```
makeMaze() {
        maze = new int[rows][columns];  

        putSquare(rows, columns, colorNumber, mainCanvas);
}
```

`makeMaze()` is called in the run() but not in `onDraw()`

```
public void run() {
    makeMaze()  
}
```

I get a `NullPointerException`

In the `onDraw()` I call another method.

```
 onDraw(Canvas conv) {
     //it also also putSquare()
    redrawMaze(conv)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know the size of your dirty rectangle, call [lockCanvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29) without parameters to lock the whole drawing area rather than passing null.